# How to preview UIWebview printing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, airprint

I want to printing UIWebView. User can choose print in portrait or landscape mode. But i don't know how to make interface preview because i can't calculate print area. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
-(void)printWebView{
UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
pic.printInfo = printInfo;
pic.printFormatter = [webView viewPrintFormatter];
pic.showsPageRange = YES;
void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
{
    if (!completed && error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};
[pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [viewPrintFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewPrintFormatter) property of UIView. 
This property allow you to get the printable format of the page that you want to print.

Comment: YES!I set : _printController.printFormatter = [_webView viewPrintFormatter]; But after that i get UIPrintFormatter object with all properties can't use for my target.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use for my target"? If you post some code, maybe, it's more easy to understand what your probelm is.